# how to surpress logging of jsf "There are some unhandled FacesMessages"

Tags: jsf

Is there a way to tell JSF to not log this error?

```
WARNING [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-28009-exec-1] org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
```